# Search Form - Execute Query - When detail record found then message

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a search sales_orders/payment_details form ...

I am searching record through enter and execute query but in some cases detail record is not found

For Example: Enter Sales Order and Execute Payment record but there is no payment made yet...

then i would like to give message ('No record found')..

please guide me the trigger and its level of execution

Thanks
Javed

Answer (score 1):

That's a master-detail form. I suggest you create it that way and let Forms worry about default data handling (querying, inserting, deleting) - use Data Block Wizard, it'll do everything right and create number of triggers which will enforce the master-detail relationship.

Once you're done, everything will just *work* - you don't have to write a single line of code.

As I don't have your tables, I used Scott's `dept` (master) and `emp` (detail). If you're familiar with that schema, you know that there are some employees in departments 10, 20 and 30, but nobody works in department 40.

Therefore, you'd want to display some message when you query department 40. On the left hand side is output for executing query on department 10; on the right is what we actually want (department 40, no employees there):

[image]

How to do that? Navigate to "Program units" in Object Navigator and edit the `QUERY_MASTER_DETAILS` trigger - it is one of those objects created by the Data Block Wizard.

Edit its code and add a few lines which will check whether detail rows exist; if not, display a message (see line #20):

```
PROCEDURE Query_Master_Details(rel_id Relation,detail VARCHAR2) IS
  oldmsg VARCHAR2(2);  -- Old Message Level Setting
  reldef VARCHAR2(5);  -- Relation Deferred Setting
BEGIN
  --
  -- Initialize Local Variable(s)
  --
  reldef := Get_Relation_Property(rel_id, DEFERRED_COORDINATION);
  oldmsg := :System.Message_Level;
  --
  -- If NOT Deferred, Goto detail and execute the query.
  --
  IF reldef = 'FALSE' THEN
    Go_Block(detail);
    Check_Package_Failure;
    :System.Message_Level := '10';
    Execute_Query;
    :System.Message_Level := oldmsg;
    
    -- I added this 4 lines:                            --> here
    if :employees.empno is null then
       message('No employees in that department');
       message('No employees in that department');
    end if; 
    -- End of lines added by LF

  ELSE
    --
    -- Relation is deferred, mark the detail block as un-coordinated
    --
    Set_Block_Property(detail, COORDINATION_STATUS, NON_COORDINATED);
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN Form_Trigger_Failure THEN
      :System.Message_Level := oldmsg;
      RAISE;
END Query_Master_Details;
```

For simplicity, I used two consecutive `message` calls which then act as if it were an alert (otherwise, that message would be displayed in the status line at the bottom of the window). If you want, you can use "real" alert; I'll leave it to you.